# How to handle frequently changing data types in SSIS

Tags: ssis, truncation

I have a project containing numerous SSIS packages. These simple packages are loading data from an external server to my internal database and not making any data transformations. I cannot control the quality and the structure of the data in the source and get it 'as is'. Most of the data comes in the nvarchar data type.

My problem is that the owner of the source database is frequently changing the length of the nvarchar fields (say, from nvarchar(500) to nvarchar(510)). This makes my packages crash on truncation.

How can I set up my packages in a way that in case of any length changes they ignore it and simply truncate the data if needed? As far as I understand I should set up my 'Error output', but I am not sure whether I should work with ODBC Source Output or with OLE DB Destination Input.

Comment: Import your data into staging tables first with nvarchar(MAX) columns that you truncate every load.  Then when inserting into your main tables do your code to trim/sutstring to force into your table lenghts.

Comment: Try changing the `ValidateExternalMetadata` property to `false` on the `ODBC Source`

Comment: I would say do not use SSIS @kirill